# Story about a scarecrow who is entitled to some land

Tags: story-identification, books

I vaguely remember reading a book years ago that went something like this:

- A scarecrow somehow comes to life.
- He somehow makes friends with a boy.
- They go on a journey for some reason.
- He finds out his late owner left him some land.
- Due to many accidents and events, every part of him is replaced — his head, his straw, etc.
- So a legal battle ensues. Is he the same scarecrow that the will referenced if he's fully replaced?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was "years ago?"  Do you remember anything about the book's cover, how long it was, hardcover vs. paperback, etc.?

Comment: Was this a children's book? It sounds as if it might be from the description.

Comment: The scarecrow of Theseus?

Comment: @DavidW maybe 2013-14?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Might this be *[The Scarecrow and His Servant](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1022883.The_Scarecrow_and_His_Servant)* by Philip Pullman, published in 2004?

[image]

According to [this review](https://www.theguardian.com/childrens-books-site/2014/oct/24/review-scarecrow-and-servant-philip-pullman) from The Guardian, a boy and a scarecrow go on a journey together, seeking the scarecrow's fortune and place of birth:

> This is story about a gullible and fun-loving scarecrow, known as Lord Scarecrow, who employs the services of a poor, quick-witted boy as his servant to help him on his journey of adventure. Together they stumble upon many obstacles **while the scarecrow searches for his fortune and tries to find his birthplace**.

And according to [this review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/philip-pullman/the-scarecrow-and-his-servant/) from kirkusreviews.com, they tangle with a lawyer representing a family who want to turn the scarecrow's valley into a rat poison factory:

> **A pair of valiant adventurers outwits a lawyer and his corporate masters in this comic fairy tale**. The Scarecrow has been stolen so often that, by the time it comes to life, it’s nowhere near its home in Spring Valley. Together with clever orphan Jack, whom he hires as a servant, the Scarecrow quests for his home. Along the way, he becomes an actor, a lover and a soldier. Each time, the Scarecrow’s foolishness is nearly their undoing until resourceful Jack saves the day. **But unbeknownst to Jack and the Scarecrow, they’re being followed by a lawyer for the wicked Buffaloni family, which wants to turn the Scarecrow’s beautiful Spring Valley into a rat poison factory**. Luckily, Jack’s cleverness and the Scarecrow’s kindness (for, though he exists to scare birds, he can’t bear to scare a baby bird or its parents) help them defeat the Buffalonis in a thoroughly amusing conclusion. Lightweight for Pullman, but witty, affectionate and fun.

I found [another review](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2004/nov/27/booksforchildrenandteenagers.philippullman) from The Guardian stating that the scarecrow replaces various body parts of his, such as his leg and head, and that there's subsequently a legal battle over whether he's still the original scarecrow or not:

> The scarecrow calls out for help: "I need another leg," he explains to Jack. "If you go and find me a leg, I shall be very obliged. Just like this one, only the opposite." Jack sets off towards a wood, comes back with the right sort of stick and slides it up the scarecrow's trousers.

> In a book of extraordinary moments, one of the best is when Jack is starving on the desert island. **He is so hungry the scarecrow suggests he should eat his, the scarecrow's, head. It's this kind of comic, elemental, crazy tenderness that this kind of narrative does best. So how will the scarecrow replace his head? It's a desert island, remember. A coconut, of course!**
>
> But such ruses have a way of rebounding on our heroes. **When the final showdown occurs - in a courtroom, with the full panoply of comic, arbitrary justice - will the scarecrow be able to claim that he is indeed the original scarecrow?** Or has he removed his own habeas corpus?

Comment: I think this is it, there's a jury and everything, and there's also the picture I vaguely remember on the last page of them living happy ever after. +1